# Run or Debug does nothing for C# code beyond suggesting extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Whenever I attempt to run or debug my C# program (doing this for the very first time) I get a [image: prompt to install an extension for C#], even though the list of installed extensions already shows [image: Microsoft extension for C#] as already installed. Beyond this nothing happens, no attempt to run or debug is ever seen. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I am changing my answer to select the top one. And hit the green button.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I am missing your point, but how does that solve OPs issue?

Comment: debugging in visual studio code requires the c# extension to be installed. Install the extension and then debug.

Comment: But as OP is stating the C# extension is installed, provided screenshots also indicates it is installed

Comment: Good point. I didn't really understand the question there. I should have answered, just hit the green button.